# Bootstrap 3.3.4 row not stretching 100% of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started using bootstrap and have 2 rows set up as such:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid">

<div class="row" id="header">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div id="logo">
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--HEADER-->

<div class="row" id="heroimage">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    </div>
</div><!--HEROIMAGE-->

</div><!--WRAPPER-->
```

But the #heroimage row isnt stretching 100% the width of the page. It appear to have a 15px margin on the right.

See screen shot here. The red bar is #header the blue is #heroimage

[image]

Any one have any idea what's causing this and how to fix?

Comment: working fine i guess http://jsfiddle.net/zwf2ak0m/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh! Found the issue almost instantly after posting this.

I had

```
#heroimage{ width: 100%;}
```

in my css.

Bootstrap doesnt like this and it's not necessary.

Comment: It doesnt  matter though, you can override bootstrap styles if you want

Comment: i don't get it if it was set to 100% why wasn't it though ?
and by removing it , it became 100% how would have that been the cause of it being 15px from the right

Comment: @eranotzap Im guessing its something to do with the Bootstrap JS file compensating for the 15px right padding the `container-fluid` adds

Comment: @eranotzap a row doesn't have a width set. Since it's a block element, it just takes all the available width. Because a row has `margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;` properties, setting the width to 100% causes it to stretch to it's parent width, positioned -15px to the left.

Comment: @redelschaap it's a block. it would stretch to it's parent's width with out setting 100%. if it has a margin-right: 15px; even with the seemingly redundant 100% setting it should still be pushed from the right .

Comment: No, a block element with `width: 100%` set is not the same as one without it. Try it with a developer toolbar on the Bootstrap website, you'll see the difference.